# Identifying a possible pathogen of a succulent plant (Haworthiopsis attenuata) presenting with small brown scales

Tags: species-identification, botany, entomology

I have a succulent (most likely [Haworthiopsis attenuata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haworthiopsis_attenuata)) that is currently not looking so hot. I recently noticed a number of small brown scales growing on multiple leaves (Eastern USA), that I think are some sort of pathogen:

- They don't appear to follow any sort of pattern like the white marks on the leaves.
- They are easily detachable with tweezers--I plucked two or three off as a test.

The best explanation I've found myself is that they're some sort of [scale insects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect), but they seem really tiny. These are about the size of a Chia seed--only a few mm across. What are these, and as a bonus, how can I get rid of them? Photos are below:

[image: zoomed out full plant picture]

[image: zoomed in to scale]

Comment: I also would say that these are scale insects. You could try brushing them with slightly soapy water. Maybe you will get better help at https://gardening.stackexchange.com/